# Exact readable screen size of Sony PRS-650

Tags: pdf, hardware, creation, libreoffice, sony-prs-650

I use a Sony PRS-650 and I often create PDF files for it with LibreOffice. These are usually documents which I read only once and I don't care about portability. (I don't read them on other devices and I'm able to change the page size if I need to.)

What page size should I set in LibreOffice to see exactly the same layout (and avoid resizing of the pages) on my PC and PRS-650? 
(Please note that there is a status line at the bottom of the screen on PRS-650 with battery charging indicator etc.)

Comment: Isn't this question too localized? The same question could be asked for any of the myriad other ebook readers.

Comment: @svick: I've [raised this on Meta](http://meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-issues-are-candidates-for-off-topic-reasons-for-the-site/69#69).

Comment: Do you want to know the screen size in pixels, minus the status bar, or the size in inches/mm minus the status bar?

Comment: @JasonDown: LibreOffice supports inches/mm, but pixels are also interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is exact enough, but based on a combination of my own manual measurements and specifications listed in [the user guide](http://pdf.crse.com/manuals/4257661113.pdf) (*warning links to pdf directly*):

- Screen resolution is 600(w) x 800(h) pixels
- Screen measurements (approx, done myself) are 92(w) x 122(h) mm
- Using [this calculator](http://easycalculation.com/pixtomm.php), that gives us a dpi of approx 44.
- Approx measurement of status bar is 5mm (using same calculator as above we get ~33 pixels)

Conclusion:

- Readable screen height is 600(w) x 767(h) pixels or 92(w) x 118(h) mm