# How to set metadata (title, author) of exported PDF documents in LibreOffice/OpenOffice.org

Tags: pdf, metadata, libreoffice

I often create ['read only once and delete' PDF files with LibreOffice](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/256/100). How can I set their metadata (title, author) properly so my Sony Reader could show it on the *Books* screen?

Answer (score 8):

Setting the title of the PDF:

- *File* menu / *Properties* / *Description* tab, *Title* field.

Setting the author:

- *Tools* menu / *Options* / *LibreOffice* / *User Data* tab, fill the *First name* and *Last name* fields,
- *File* menu / *Properties* / *General* tab, tick the *Apply user data* checkbox,
- press the *Reset* button (it's near to the *Apply user data* checkbox).

The *Reset* button refreshes the currently edited document's author field (based on the data given in the *User Data* field), when you press it the author is showed immediately on the same *General Tab*, near the *Created* label.